# What are customary items for an hourly lawyer to bill?

Tags: united-kingdom, fees

This question presumes the hourly billing method and the lawyer's perspective. To avoid broadness, I restrict this question to the UK (but please advise whether I should remove this).

I already know of the following:

- expenses incurred for a client's case (e.g.: fees for court, experts, and other lawyers; travelling)
- meetings
- reading, preparing, negotiating and working on notes and documents (e.g.: of meetings, of telephone calls and of proceedings)
- research;
- composing and receiving correspondence (e.g.: letters, faxes, email, telephone calls)
- attending court or other formal proceedings, including waiting time;

Answer (score 1):

Lawyers generally will bill clients for two broad categories:

- Professional fees (time spent working on a client's matter); and
- Cost recovery (lodging forms, printing, faxing, photocopying, etc)

Anything that falls within these two groups is fair game, including everything you've mentioned in your question.

I suspect it's not possible to devise a comprehensive list of items that may be billed, as it will depend largely on the matter being worked on.